# laravel route:list filter by controller

Tags: php, laravel, routes, command-line-interface

In my Laravel 10 project, I have two controllers with the same name but in a different namespace. For these controllers I would like to list all the routes in my CLI, thus I would like to [filter my routes in my CLI](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#the-route-list) based on controller name.

You can find the filter flags for the `route:list` command by typing `php artisan route:list --help` as it will contain the following output (output shortened for brevity):

```
Options:
      --method[=METHOD]            Filter the routes by method
      --name[=NAME]                Filter the routes by name
      --domain[=DOMAIN]            Filter the routes by domain
      --path[=PATH]                Only show routes matching the given path pattern
      etc...
```

As you can see, no filter for the controller name is given. How can one still get a list of all routes that have a given controller name?

Comment: You can always `grep` the results. `php artisan route:list | grep 'Namespace\Controller'`. You may need to double the slash, though. `grep 'Namespace\\Controller'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no filter option for this type of search (yet), one can use a work around using a tool like [grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) as so: `php artisan route:list | grep 'Namespace\\Controller'`. Note that in order to make it work, I needed to double the slash.

Unfortunately, as a side effect, the colors of my output get removed. Using `grep --color=always` did not solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I use Laravel 10 and have two controllers called KlantController and KlantLeveringController

Using `php artisan route:list --name=klant` shows me:

```
 GET|HEAD        klant ................................................................................................................................................... klant.index › KlantController@index
  POST            klant ................................................................................................................................................... klant.store › KlantController@store
  GET|HEAD        klant/create .......................................................................................................................................... klant.create › KlantController@create
  GET|HEAD        klant/{klant} ............................................................................................................................................. klant.show › KlantController@show
  PUT|PATCH       klant/{klant} ......................................................................................................................................... klant.update › KlantController@update
  DELETE          klant/{klant} ....................................................................................................................................... klant.destroy › KlantController@destroy
  GET|HEAD        klant/{klant}/edit ........................................................................................................................................ klant.edit › KlantController@edit
  GET|HEAD        klant/{klant}/levering ................................................................................................................. klant.levering.index › KlantLeveringController@index
  POST            klant/{klant}/levering ................................................................................................................. klant.levering.store › KlantLeveringController@store
  GET|HEAD        klant/{klant}/levering/create ........................................................................................................ klant.levering.create › KlantLeveringController@create
  GET|HEAD        klant/{klant}/levering/{levering} ........................................................................................................ klant.levering.show › KlantLeveringController@show
  PUT|PATCH       klant/{klant}/levering/{levering} .................................................................................................... klant.levering.update › KlantLeveringController@update
  DELETE          klant/{klant}/levering/{levering} .................................................................................................. klant.levering.destroy › KlantLeveringController@destroy
  GET|HEAD        klant/{klant}/levering/{levering}/edit ................................................................................................... klant.levering.edit › KlantLeveringController@edit
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer my question. I would like to filter by the name of the controller